# Passing C variable in Shell command

Tags: c, shell, system

I am stuck at a problem. I want to use C variable in a shell command (`dd`).

Suppose `abc.c` is my C program.

```
int main()
 {
    int block = 1313; /*any integer */
    system("dd if=device of=output-file bs=4096 count=1 skip=$((block))");
    return 0;
 }
```

Now, if I use 1313 in place of `block` in the `dd` command then it works fine. But when I write `block` then it writes zeros in output-file as `block` is a C program variable and is used in the shell command.

Comment: You haven't googled this one, have you. And you don't know the difference between PHP and C, do you.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

```
char buf[256];
const int block = 1313;
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf,
         "dd if=device of=output-file bs=4096 count=1 skip=%d", block);
system(buf);
```